# How to pipe stdout in realtime to a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

I'm trying to pipe the lines outputted from a program to another script which would in realtime read the lines and depending on whats in the line do something.

So for example the output is

```
$program.exe 
Program Started
Processing info
Work Set Started
Work Set Ended
Results are..
Ending Program
```

I want that to be piped to a script which can trigger another program when the above program outputs "Work Set Started"

I have tried the following in my trigger.bat

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
    IF "%%B" == "Work Set Started" (
        ProgramB.exe
        )
)

ENDLOCAL
```

When I run the following

```
$program.exe | trigger.bat
```

ProgramB.exe is not launched in real time but the for loop from trigger.bat executes after it collects all the output from the pipe.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to use PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

The `FOR /F` command first collects all the output from the executed command, and start to process each output line until the command ends.

You may modify your `trigger.bat` file code this way:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

:nextLine
set /P "line="
echo Line received: "%line%"
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ("%line%") DO (
   IF "%%B" == "Work Set Started" ECHO ProgramB.exe
   IF "%%B" neq "Ending Program" GOTO NextLine
)
```

However, it may be some synchronization problems if the output of your `$program.exe` is generated too fast. I tested this code using this `output.txt` file:

```
[1]$program.exe 
[2]Program Started
[3]Processing info
[4]Work Set Started
[5]Work Set Ended
[6]Results are..
[7]Ending Program
```

If I just do this: `type output.txt | trigger.bat` the program fail, but if the output lines are generated slowly via this `output.bat` program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (output.txt) do (
   set /A "rand=!random! %% 4 + 2"
   ping -n !rand! localhost > NUL
   echo %%a
)
```

... then the method works correctly:

```
C:\> output.bat | trigger.bat
Line received: "[1]$program.exe "
Line received: "[2]Program Started"
Line received: "[3]Processing info"
Line received: "[4]Work Set Started"
ProgramB.exe
Line received: "[5]Work Set Ended"
Line received: "[6]Results are.."
Line received: "[7]Ending Program"
```

So you need to test this method for your particular case...

Answer (score 1):

Tested with a simple code to generate the output as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"programOutput.txt" (
        echo(Program Started
        echo(Processing info
        echo(Work Set Started
        echo(Work Set Ended
        echo(Results are..
        echo(Ending Program    
    )

    set program=findstr "^" programOutput.txt

    %program% | trigger.cmd
```

The `trigger.cmd` code could be something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    if "%~1"==".monitor." ( call :monitor ) else ( call :start )
    goto :eof

:start    
    echo .... Entering monitor
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~n0.%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (
        type nul >"%%~ft"
        findstr "^" > "%%~ft" | ( <"%%~ft" "%~f0" .monitor. & echo Start program B here )
    ) & 2>nul del /q "%%~ft"
    echo .... Main program ended - Leaving monitor
    goto :eof

:monitor
    rem Try to read data. In case of failure wait and repeat
    set /p "data=" || (
        >nul ping -n 2 "" 
        goto :monitor
    )
    echo(.... monitor has retrieved [%data%]
    if /i "%data%"=="Work Set Started" (
        echo(.... !!! : detected work set start. Leaving monitor
        goto :eof
    )
    rem No end of monitoring condition found. Try again
    goto :monitor
```

As Aacini indicates,

- The problem with `for /f` is that all the data has to be retrieved before starting to process it.
- The problem with the loop using `set /p` inside a pipe is the syncronization of both sides of the pipe.

But there is a workaround for the problem. You can use an intermediate file. That is, you can redirect the output of your command to a file and, at the same time that the program is writting, you can read from the file. Not bulletproof but more stable.

A safer way of deal with it is use some way of indicating where each line starts. This is another `trigger.cmd` alternative that uses a `find /n` command to process the output of the program that is being processed in the monitoring loop. If the fist character in the input buffer is `[` we will assume we have found the start of a line, else, it is a line continuation.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    if "%~1"==".monitor." ( call :monitor ) else ( call :start )
    goto :eof

:start    
    echo .... Entering monitor
    set "buffer="
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~n0.%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (
        type nul >"%%~ft"
        find /n /v "" > "%%~ft" | ( <"%%~ft" "%~f0" .monitor. & echo Start program B here )
    ) & 2>nul del /q "%%~ft"
    echo .... Main program ended - Leaving monitor
    goto :eof


:monitor
    rem Try to read data. In case of failure wait and repeat
    set /p "data=" || (
        >nul ping -n 2 "" 
        goto :monitor
    )
    echo(.... monitor has retrieved [%data%]

    rem The output of the process is being numerated by find /n
    rem so each line is in the form [9]xxxxxxx
    if not "%data:~0,1%"=="[" (
        rem If we don not have a line start, append to previous buffer
        set "buffer=%buffer%%data%"
    ) else (
        rem New line found to process
        set "buffer=%data%"
    )

    rem Remove initial [number] data
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=]" %%a in ("%buffer%") do (
        echo(.... checking program output [%%a]
        if /i "%%a"=="Work Set Started" (
            echo(.... !!! detected work set start. Leaving monitor
            goto :eof
        )
    )

    rem No end of monitoring condition found. Try again
    goto :monitor
```

**note**: While not aware at the time of writting previous code, I've duplicated (and not in the best way) the work of dbenham. Please, refer to [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32615#p32615) for a much improved version of the same idea.